# Add additional tooltip from from JSON Array

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts, angular-highcharts

I have a JSON array like this:

```
chart_data = [
{category: 'A', per: '0.74', total: 10294, in: 5651, out: 5661},
{category: 'B', per: '0.72', total: 10294, in: 5556, out: 7751},
{category: 'C', per: '0.68', total: 10294, in: 5598, out: 5991},
{category: 'D', per: '0.54', total: 10294, in: 6551, out: 5001}
]
```

now I am showing the data in the column chart where I am using per column chart data where in Highcharts the only tooltip visible is **"per"** but I want to show **"total, in, out"** all of them in the tooltip.

Here's my HighChart Code:

```
    plotColumnChart(chart_data:any, chart_config: any){
  
  let columnChartSeries = [];
  let categories = [];
  let columnChartData = {
    exporting: {
      chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
          plotOptions: {
              series: {
                  dataLabels: {
                      enabled: true
                  }
              }
          }
      },
      fallbackToExportServer: false
  },
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      borderColor: '#c1e1c182',
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderRadius: 5,
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
    },
    title: {
      text: chart_config['name'],
      x: -20,
      style: {
        color: '#0D6ABF',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: chart_data.map(function(point:any){
        return [(<any>Object).values(point)[0]]
    }),
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      gridLineColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      tickInterval: 20,
      max:100,
      gridLineColor: '#ffffff',
      title: {
        text: null,
        align: null
      },
      labels: {
        overflow: 'justify'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: false,
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderRadius: 10,
      style: {
        color: 'white'
      },
      useHTML: true,
      borderWidth: 3,
      headerFormat: '<b style="color: #fff;">{point.x}</b><br/>',
      formatter: function() {

      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          distance: "-80%",
          pointFormat: '{point.y}%',
          },
        },
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.5,
        borderWidth: 0,
        showInLegend: true, 
        zones:[{
                  value: chart_config['color-format'][0],        // Values up to 50 (not including) ...
                  color: '#FA5F55'  // ... have the this color.
                },
                {
                  value: chart_config['color-format'][1],        // Values up to 60/70 (not including) ...
                  color: '#FFBF00' // ... have the this color.
                },
                {
                  color: '#98FB98' // Values greater than 70 ... have the this color.
                }                
              ],
              }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: '', //chart_config['name'],
        color: '', //'#98FB98',
        pointWidth: 20,
        data: chart_data.map(function(point:any){                
            return [
              Number(
                    (
                      parseFloat(
                        
                        (<any>Object).values(point)[1]
                        
                        )*100                          
                      ).toFixed(0)
                  )
              ]
          })
      },
    ]
  } as any;

  Highcharts.chart(chart_config['id'], columnChartData);
  
}
```

And `chart_config = {"id": 'column-chart', "name": 'ABC', 'color-format': [50, 70]};`

Can anybody help me to achieve this by writing a **formatter** function for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to get other values from the chart level if you don't provide them in the data. In your example, only "per" value is passed to the `series.data` . After parsing data to the relevant format, you will also need to define `series.keys` in order to have access to these options.

```
//Data parsing to the two dimensional array
let new_chart_data = [];

chart_data.forEach(data => {
  data.per = Number(data.per)
  new_chart_data.push([data.category, data.per, data.total, data.in, data.out])
})

//Chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
        console.log(this.options)
      return `<b>Per:</b> ${this.y}</br><b>Total:</b> ${this.total}</br><b>In:</b> ${this.in}</br><b>Out:</b> ${this.out}</br>`
    }
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    keys: ['name', 'y', 'total', 'in', 'out'],
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: new_chart_data
  }]
});
```

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.keys

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3dh2m79c/

Comment: what about if the keys are dynamic, how do I handle that?

Comment: Generally, this is a more JS-related question. You can use any JS method to find the relevant way to show data in the `formatter()`. Here is an example you can base on: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r27z3yj4/

Comment: Your solution is working in pure JS but along with angular "this" keyword is pointing to component instead of chart.

Comment: Here is a demo in the Highcharts Angular Wrapper: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-yvp4b9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this updated demo but still in my code "this" keyword still points to my component.

Comment: I am getting this when I am using the below code:

          formatter: function(event: any) {             
            console.log("Bar Point Details: ",this);
            console.log("Components Details: ",that);
            }

Answer: {x: Array(1), y: 69, color: '#FFBF00', colorIndex: 0, key: 'TestName', …} this is what I am getting from 1st console but not able to access it's values using "this.x" and "this.y".

Can you tell me how can I achieve that?

Comment: I've noticed you created a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73309631/keys-are-inaccessible-of-json-object-in-angular-highcharts, so I will continue there

Comment: Using the event along with the formatter function, I am able to modify the tooltips.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public formatter(row): string {
   return row ? `${row.per}, ${row.in}, ${row.out}` : null;
}
```

Comment: Ale - How can I use your code snippet in my code?

Comment: @Himanshu can you add console.log(this) inside your formatter function and post the result?

Comment: Getting something like this: 
Inside Formatter Function: 

{x: Array(1), y: 74, color: '#FA5F55', colorIndex: 0, key: Array(1), …}

Comment: @Himanshu look at this one https://jsfiddle.net/Lhpo1k2f/4/

Comment: Didn't work out.